# Add legend below plot in plotyy

Tags: matlab, plot

**Problem**

I am plotting a graph with a legend but the legend keeps on appearing above the lines of the graph.
How can I get the legend to be below the graph, as for example you can choose in Excel ?

**Code**

I am using the following code:

```
h=figure
hold on
yyaxis left
l1=plot(summary(:,1),summary(:,2))
l2=plot(summary(:,1),summary(:,3))
hYLabel=ylabel('US$') 

yyaxis right
r1=plot(summary(:,1),(summary(:,8)))
r2=plot(summary(:,1),summary(:,15))
hYLabel=ylabel('Test')
hTitle=title('Test);
hXLabel = xlabel('Test');
hLegend=legend([l1,l2,r1,r2], 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4');
set([gca,hTitle,hXLabel,hYLabel,hLegend] , 'FontName'   , 'Helvetica','FontSize', 8) 
set(hTitle,'FontSize', 11) 
set(gca,'LineWidth',1.0)


set(l1, 'LineWidth',1.5,'LineStyle','-')
set(l2, 'LineWidth',1.5,'LineStyle','-.')
set(r1, 'LineWidth',1.5,'LineStyle','-')
set(r2, 'LineWidth',1.5,'LineStyle','-.')
hold off
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Location attribute](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html#inputarg_Location). If you want it to be below the x-axis, use the parameter `'southoutside'`.

In this case:

```
hLegend=legend([l1,l2,r1,r2], 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4', ...
   'Location', 'southoutside');
```

To get the legends in a line instead of beneath each other, use `'Orientation'`:

```
hLegend=legend([l1,l2,r1,r2], 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4', ...
   'Location', 'southoutside', 'Orientation','horizontal')
```

If you want it inside, but you don't know where the best position is before you create the plot, use the parameter `'best'`. From the documentation:

> `best`: Inside axes where least conflict with data in plot

If you know where the best location is, then you can choose any of the other options, such as:

```
'north'      Inside top of axes
'south'      Inside bottom of axes
'east'       Inside right of axes
'west'       Inside left of axes
'northeast'  Inside top-right of axes (default for 2-D axes)
'northwest'  Inside top-left of axes
.....        ......
```